# use of Article in Sentences

Tags: verbs, nouns, adjectives, adverbs, pronouns

The school provides services of art teacher.
or School provides the services of art teacher.
which one is correct

Comment: Neither is correct.

You need" The school provides the services of an art teacher".

Quite separately, that will be very unlikely to sound idomatic.

Answer (score 0):

One definite article and one indefinite article are required. The school provides **the** services of **an** art teacher. The indefinite article is 'an' because the word 'art' starts with a vowel sound.

Comment: However, if the art teacher is already under discussion, then *the* art teacher may be more appropriate.